# How do I show actual dates in a daily time series in R?

Tags: r, date, time-series

I've created a daily time series. Original data:

```
> head(platinum)
        Date Hong.Kong.8.30
1 2019-12-19            938
2 2019-12-18            929
3 2019-12-17            933
4 2019-12-16            931
5 2019-12-13            947
6 2019-12-12            943
```

I used the `zoo` package, and it still showed dates:

```
> plat2=read.zoo(platinum)
> tail(plat2,30)
2019-11-08 2019-11-11 2019-11-12 2019-11-13 2019-11-14 2019-11-15 
       913        894        880        876        878        885 
2019-11-18 2019-11-19 2019-11-20 2019-11-21 2019-11-22 2019-11-25 
       896        899        915        923        917        897
```

After `as.ts`, however, the dates are stored as integers:

```
> as.ts(plat2)
Time Series:
Start = 8217 
End = 18249 
Frequency = 1
```

And the plot is in intergers too:
[time series plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK2WI.png)

I want the x axis to have intervals of a decade. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Runnable code to reproduce a snippet of your data would be really helpful for quickly testing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to convert it to a `ts` for plotting ?
Plotting it from the `zoo` conversion seems fine.

If you need a specific axis, you can then fiddle with the `axis()` function as shown below.

```
# make dummy data
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("1980-01-01"), 
                            as.Date("2019-01-01"), by = "month"),
                 val = rnorm(469))

# read w/ zoo
df_zoo <- read.zoo(df)

# default plot
plot(df_zoo, main = "zoo plot")

# custom axis plot
plot(df_zoo, xaxt = "n", main = "zoo plot w/ modified axis")

tks <- seq(min(df$date), max(df$date), by = "10 years")
axis(1, at = tks, labels = tks, cex.axis = .7)
```

plots :

[image]